# Get most favorit rooms mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this data in my database which i want get most room_id got in favorit by users .

Tablename: `favorit_rooms`

```
 id    |   userid   |  room_id|   favorit

  1    |  114       | 1       |    1
  2    |  45        | 1       |    0
  3    |  45        | 5       |    1
  4    |  47        | 1       |    1
  5    |  114       | 3       |    1
  6    |  120       | 1       |    1
  7    |  114       | 2       |    1
  8    |  45        | 2       |    1
  9    |  45        | 3       |    1
 10    |  45        | 12      |    1
 11    |  131       | 1       |    0
```

I tryed to group by room_id and userid but didnt work . and then i want to order them by the most favorit to less .Of course make attention to that favorit is not 0 .

```
 SELECT id,room_id,count(userid) as countusers FROM favorit_rooms 
 GROUP BY room_id,favorit  
 ORDER by room_id,favorit desc LIMIT 5
```

My wished result is :

```
       room_id    countusers 

        1          3        
        2          2        
        3          2        
        5          1        
        12         1
```

userid  AND  room_id are index together so there is no dublicates .

How do i accomplish this thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change the grouping a bit and add a where clause. This should do what you want:

```
SELECT room_id, count(userid) AS countusers 
FROM favorit_rooms 
WHERE favorit = 1
GROUP BY room_id
ORDER by countusers DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: yours also is working and easier without distinct as exactly you said its index . thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be this

```
SELECT  room_id, count(distinct userid) as countusers 
FROM favorit_rooms 
WHERE favorit = 1
GROUP BY room_id,favorit  
ORDER by count(distinct userid) desc LIMIT 5
```

Comment: this looks working :) , wanna try the other answer only to see the difference

Comment: The question states that _userid AND room_id are index together so there is no duplicates._ so distinct isn't really needed.

Comment: the distinct  in count should be for count only distinct userid otherwise you count eg userid 45  five times but should be counted one only ..